# Opacity overlap within the same OpenGl TriStrip in LibGdx

Tags: opengl, libgdx

While my problem lies strictly in the opacity of the tristrip, I'd like to give some context first.

Recently I started developing a game through LibGdx which involves 2D circles which bounce around the screen. So as to provide a neat graphical effect, I created a small system that would provide a "tail" to the actors, which would fade over time. Visually, it looks like this:

[Nice Trail Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBL1Q.png)

Now that ended up looking satisfactory. My problem, however, lies in situation where parts of the "trail" effect overlap, creating an ugly artifact which I would guess is the sum of the opacities of the points.

[Ugly Trail Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzoFB.png)

I believe this problem lies in the way with which the tristrip is drawn, specifically with the blending methods used. 
The code used to generate the trail is as follows:

```
Array<Vector2> tristrip = new Array<Vector2>(); //Contains the vector information for OpenGL to build the strip.
Array<Vector2> texcoord = new Array<Vector2>(); //Contains the opacity information for the corresponding tristrip point.

// ... Code Here.... //


gl20.begin(camera.combined, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int i = 0; i < tristrip.size; i++) {
        if (i == batchSize) {
            gl20.end();
            gl20.begin(camera.combined, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        }

        Vector2 point = tristrip.get(i);
        Vector2 textcoord = texcoord.get(i);
        gl20.color(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);  // Color.WHITE
        gl20.texCoord(textcoord.x, 0f);
        gl20.vertex(point.x, point.y, 0);
    }
gl20.end();
```

It is also important to note that the draw function for the strip is called within another class, in this fashion:

```
private void renderFX() {
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    Array<Ball> balls = mainstage.getBalls();

    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size; i++) { //Draws the trails for each actor
        balls.get(i).drawFX();
    }

}
```

Is this problem a rookie mistake on my part, or was my implementation of the drawing of the vector array **tristrip** flawed from the start? How can I fix the blending issue in order to create smoother trails even in the presence of sharp curves?

Thanks in advance...

Edit: Since originally asking this question, I've experimented with some possible solutions, also implementing Deniz Yılmaz's suggestion of using a FBO to facilitate blending. Given that, my render function currently looks like this:

```
private void renderFX() {
    frameBuffer.begin();

    Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    Gdx.gl20.glStencilOp(GL20.GL_KEEP, GL20.GL_INCR, GL20.GL_INCR);
    Gdx.gl20.glStencilMask(0xFF);

    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    Array<Ball> balls = mainstage.getBalls();

    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size; i++) {

        Gdx.gl20.glStencilFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL, 0, 0xFF);

        balls.get(i).drawFX(1f, Color.RED);
    }
    frameBuffer.end();

}
```

As shown, I've also experimented with stencils so as to try and mask the overlapping portion of the trail. This approach, however, results in the following visuals:

[Stenciled Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDrhg.jpg)

Again, this is not ideal, and has made me realize that approaching this problem by masking is not a good idea, as the opacity gradient will never be smooth in the corners as there will always be a sharp line between the two overlapping opacity values, even if somehow the logic prevents blending.

Given that, how else could I approach this problem? Should I scrap this method entirely if I plan to achieve a smooth gradient for this trail effect?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glBlendFunc() is useless in this case because by default the values calculated based on the blend function are added.

So something like glBlendEquation(GL_MAX) needed

BUT

blending alone won't work, since it can't tell the difference between what is the background and what is the overlapping shapes.

Instead use FrameBuffer to draw trail with a glBlendEquation.

https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/FrameBufferObjects